# DataTable pagination removes forms

Tags: jquery, forms, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables. I have a table with ID `read` and each table row is inside a form.

When I make pagination with the `$('#read').DataTable()` the forms disappear and I can't figure why?

Comment: Add your HTML markup to the question. The solution is to wrap entire table in `<form>` tag and not individual rows as that is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course they do.

The correct table html structure is:

```
<table>
    <thead><!--optional-->
      <tr><!--optional-->
        <td></td><!--optional th can also be used-->
      </tr><!--optional-->
    </thead><!--optional-->
    <tbody><!--optional-->
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody><!--optional-->
    <tfoot><!--optional-->
      <tr><!--optional-->
        <td></td><!--optional th can also be used-->
      </tr><!--optional-->
    </tfoot><!--optional-->
</table>
```

For more info see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html

Therefore enclosing a `<tr>` element in a `<form>` element is not valid syntax (that's why they get stripped-off by Datatables)

I would suggest that you re-think the way you want your Datatables to work. To update rows you can use http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/ . 
To update the entire table you can use regular jquery-ajax api http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ .

Comment: I found a solution. Instead of <form> being a parent element, I moved it below, so <tr> is parent element now. And it works.